# verify the central limit theorem of chi sq distribution

Tags: r, statistics, distribution

hi i have a question on verifying the central limit theorem using R.

the question was to use data generated from different statistical distribution n see if the sample means follow normal distribution .

i am using this code

```
X <- replicate(20, rchisq(20,20))
X_bar <- colMeans(X)
hist(X_bar)
```

and then increasing the number of my samples by 5 in each interval. ie. 20, 25, 30, 25, ... then i will using the KS test shapiro test available in R to test for their normality.

question is should i first define a population of 1000 first then take different samples of size 20 and then running my tests or is it possible to do so using those codes i have written above? this is because i read the defnition that CLT takes different combination of sample size N from a population to create population of means.

any help is greatly appreciated! thank you !

anyone?!!???

update: i saw a video on utube to verify CLT but he uses rnorm n not rchisq.

```
pop_size<-1000
sample_size<-15
repeated_sample<-100 
x<-rchisq(20,20) 
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for (i in 1:repeated_sample){
temp_xx<-sample(x,size=sample_size,replace=TRUE)
if(exists("smpl_x")==TRUE){
temp_xx1<-data.frame(x_bar=c(mean(temp_xx)),var_x=c(var(temp_xx)))
smpl_x<-rbind(smpl_x,temp_xx1)
rm(temp_xx1)
}else{
smpl_x<-data.frame(x_bar=c(mean(temp_xx)),var_x=c(var(temp_xx)))
}
plot(hist(temp_xx))
```

will this code work to detect the normality of chi sq distributions?

Comment: For those interested, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306262/finding-distribution-of-sample-mean-by-central-limit-theorem) is what faith is referring to

Comment: is it possible to shift this question to the math side? and how would i do that?

Comment: This should probably go to crossvalidated.com

Comment: There may be a missing close brace in the code above.